# multiple onCreate(Bundle under one activity for webview and button

Tags: java, android, eclipse, webview

I built a web app, and I am making a wrapper to put it on the app store.  I have a main page, or start page for the app, and the submit button successfully loads my webview page, and the app works well.

I wanted to add a small webview above the submit button where I could display updated news before users enter the app, such as new terms of use.

I followed examples to get the webview to load on the main page, and it works - the content is displayed, but when I add the webview, the submit button doesn't work any longer.

Eclipse throws an error "Duplicate Method OnCreate(Bundle) in type TOS, so I tried changing OnCreate to OnStart or OnCreateView for the button.  It renders from the layout xml, but there is no functionality.  I'm certain it is a novice syntax error, so I've just posted the Tos.java code:

```
 package com.packagename.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

 public class Tos extends Activity {


    private Button button;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Context context = this;

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tos);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUrl);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Mapp.class);
            startActivity(intent);
          }

        });

    }


     private WebView TermswebView;

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_tos);

            WebView TermswebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

            TermswebView.loadUrl(someURL");

        };

    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need only one onCreate method for each **Activity** not object, which is where you're thinking(I assume) that you need multiple onCreate methods.

So.. just merge the two you have...

```
 public class Tos extends Activity {

     //UI ELEMENTS
    private Button button;
    private WebView TermswebView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Context context = this;

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tos);
    TermswebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    TermswebView.loadUrl("http://www.barglance.com/assets/tos/tos.php");


    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUrl);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Mapp.class);
        startActivity(intent);
      }

    });

}
```

I hope this helps. For more information about activities and what onCreate actually does and when it's called, refer to [Android Docs - Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, I get an null pointer exception in eclipse when I use this code, on the line with Termswebview.loadUrl(.  I'm pretty sure this is a different issue, so I'm accepting your answer because you gave me the proper syntax structure, which was what I was looking for.  Thank you.

Comment: I found a syntax error ( ? ) in my xml layout file.  Now it works perfectly.  Thank you for your kind aid.  I also upvoted the answer.